# Fast clicks cause the slide view to work incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

Here is the working demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/Evqqp/1/

Please check the demo to easily understand the issue. Click on the arrows fast and you will see the view mess up.

I understand it might be because of the 300ms animation i do. What is a clean way to handle the clicks such that it does not mess up the view. I can use a flag to check if the previous click action is complete. But i wanted to seek opinions if there is a better way to do this.

Code where i do the animate

```
$(".rightArrow").on("click", function () {
    if ((Math.abs(parseInt($(".slideBox").css("margin-left"))) + $(".mainDiv").width()) < $(".slideBox").width()) {
        $(".slideBox").animate({
            "margin-left": parseInt($(".slideBox").css("margin-left")) - $(".mainDiv").width()
        }, 300, checkRightArrow);
        $(".leftArrow").show();
    } else {
        $(".rightArrow").hide();
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: `stop()` would do the trick. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your element is currently animated with the following

```
if(!$('#myElement').is(':animated'))
{
    // Do your animation here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

```
$(".slideBox").stop(true,true).animate({
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever working with animations you should always [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the previous animation on the element before animating it again.

```
$(".slideBox").stop(true, true).animate(...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Evqqp/4/

Comment: There is problem here.. When you click fast, it will end up in a empty slide.

Comment: @ksskr that is because your calculations are wrong, not because the animation is not fixed. you should not rely on the arrow being present to prevent the user from over-scrolling. this check should be in the click handler of the arrows.

Comment: adding a check for is "animated" worked. I agree there are other ways to achieve what i did.Like setting margin-left to a var and then calling the animate, in which case i can use the stop like you suggested. Thanks though. working version here http://jsfiddle.net/Evqqp/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

after:

```
$(".rightArrow").on("click", function () {
```

so:

```
$(".rightArrow").on("click", function () {
     event.stopPropagation();
     ...
```

Comment: Don't think this would make any difference. The problem is with the animation queue, not any event handlers.